# Everything is wrong with my notification

Tags: android, notifications

My app is supposed to issue notification from time to time. My smartphone's android version is lollipop 5.1. And my phone is Xiaomi. What's wrong with the notification is:

1.Large and small icons are not showing up but in KitKat android version small icon is working just fine and in the name of the large icon, the small one is being used in its place.

2.Notification style isn't being changed.(I've tried NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle)

Here's my code:

```
// TO SET LARGE ICON
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_stat_onesignal_default);
// ASSIGN INBOX STYLE NOTIFICATION
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
    bigText.setBigContentTitle("some title");
    bigText.setSummaryText("Author: unknown");
// NOTIFICATION
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker("Alert!")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_small24)
                    .setContentTitle("some title")
                    .setContentText(blah blah)
                    .setStyle(bigText);
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//to post your notification to the notification bar
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: How does your notification icon looks like? Could you add some images?

Comment: Notification style will only be noticeable when the notification is expanded.

Comment: The android icon like the one in the tag android(see up)

Comment: @EugenPechanec no, not even there

Comment: What do you mean? Either big style *is applied* and the notification *can be expanded*, or it's not applied and the notification cannot be expanded. I'm talking about your second issue, not the icon.

Comment: I'm also talking about the latter issue. I think somehow it hasn't applied. The code is right before you.